# How do I start 2 nodes in the elastic-search cluster?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, configuration

I can't find good information on making 2 node servers running in elastic-search cluster.

I just want a clear explanation of what commands I have to run or what I have to change in the elastic.yml config file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not using automatic discovery:

identical for all nodes

```
cluster.name: My-Cluster-Name
```

specific per node

```
node.name: [node name]
network.host: [hostname]
http.port: 92xx 
transport.tcp.port: 93xx
```

(If they run on the same host, they need different ports. If they run on two different hosts, you can use the same port numbers)

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["server1:9300","server2:9300","server2:9301"]
```

Here you list all the nodes in your cluster with host:port

```
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
#This must be set to minimum (number of nodes/2) + 1 to avoid "split brains". I.e. for two or three nodes you would set it to 2
discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout: 600s
```

Not mandatory, but if the network has issues you don't want the cluster to start panicking too quickly

The important points are that if you don't use multicast discovery, all the nodes need to know the host and port of all other nodes, and this has to be set in the elasticsearch.yml files. If you only use one node per host you can use the default 9200 and 9300 ports.

Once the nodes are set up you just start them all and check the output. they should log that they have found the other nodes, and you can view the active nodes using the _cat/nodes API:

```
http://server1:9200/_cat/nodes?v&h=id,ip,port,v,m,d,fdp,r,get.current,n,u
```

Each node should have its own copy of the elasticsearch software and will store its own data in the /data folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot but two questions: what is the _cat/nodes API and can you give an example of how to write the port with the host name in uncast hosts?

Comment: The _cat API is intended for human users to quickly get information about the elastic cluster, see more details here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html
Not 100% sure what you mean by your second question though.
How/where are you hosting your elasticsearch services?